# LDAP server configuration is not working in Sakai 22.1

Tags: sakai

I have installed Sakai 22.1 and the LMS is running fine. Now I need to integrate the instance to support authentication against LDAP server users (external users) as well as internal users.

To integrate with the LDAP I have uncommented the  in components.xml and then modified the unboundid-ldap.xml according to the documentation at https://sakaiproject.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/32201507026/Sakai+22+LDAP+CAS+Configuration in the section "Add  LDAP to Sakai".

The properties that I have changed are:

```
<property name="ldapHost">
 <list>
     <value>ldap.server.com</value>
</list>
</property>


<property name="ldapPort">
<list>
   <value>389</value>
</list>
</property>


<property name="ldapUser">
   <value>CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=ldap,DC=server,DC=com</value>
</property>


<property name="ldapPassword">
   <value>my secret password here</value>
</property>


<property name="autoBind">
   <value>true</value>
</property>


<property name="basePath">
   <value>dc=ldap,dc=server,dc=com</value>
</property>
```

I haven't touched any other stuff in the unboundid-ldap.xml file.

Now when I start the tomcat server and try to login with the LDAP users,  I do not get authenticated but I can only authenticate with the internal users.

Why is this happening? Do I need to make any other changes to the Sakai? Any guidance on setting up LDAP would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **uid** to **sAMAccountName** for the key **login** in the unboundid-ldap.xml.

```
<property name="attributeMappings">
   <map>
        <entry key="login"><value>sAMAccountName</value></entry>         
        <entry key="firstName"><value>givenName</value></entry> 
        <entry key="preferredFirstName"><value>preferredName</value></entry>
        <entry key="lastName"><value>sn</value></entry> 
        <entry key="email"><value>mail</value></entry>  
        <entry key="groupMembership"><value>groupMembership</value></entry>   
        <entry key="jpegPhoto"><value>jpegPhoto</value></entry>   
    </map>
</property>
```